# htaccess rule to redirect url from url parameter to query string

Tags: .htaccess

I want to convert last `/` to `?` for a url.

For eg. : `/custom/2342546578` to `custom?2342546578` using htaccess rule.

where `custom` is my page and last string is the unique id for customer identification.

How to use htaccess rule for redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  the following RewriteRule 
in your `root/.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^custom/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ /custom?$1 [L]
```

This will rewrite your url from `/custom/123` to `/custom?123` .

Comment: The id may be alpanumeric not numeric. And I want to redirect url not rewrite.

Comment: I have updated the pattern to accept alpha numbric charecters.  Change `[L]` to `[L,R]` if you want to redirect the request instead of rewriting it .

Comment: The link showing 500 internal server error after using this rule.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo when I updated the post. I fixed it . Can you copy the code again?